# webpack compiles with warnings, but the warning messages are blank

Tags: windows, npm, webpack, uglifyjs

The output looks like:

```
WARNING  Compiled with 20 warnings4:38:29 PM

warning

warning
```

And so on, "warning" 20 times, but not one bleeping warning message.

My webpack configuration looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins : [ new ImageminPlugin( {
        optipng  : { optimizationLevel : 2 },
        gifsicle : { optimizationLevel : 3 },
        pngquant : {
            quality : '65-90',
            speed   : 4,
        },
        svgo     : {
            plugins : [ { removeUnknownsAndDefaults : false }, { cleanupIDs : false }, { removeViewBox : false } ],
        },
        plugins  : [ imageminMozjpeg( { quality : 75 } ) ],
        disable  : ( config.enabled.watcher ),
    } ), new UglifyJsPlugin( {
        uglifyOptions : {
            ecma     : 5,
            compress : {
                drop_console : true,
            },
            warnings : true,
        },
    } ) ],
};
```

If I set `warnings` to `false` under `uglifyOptions`, all but 2 of the warnings go away, so all I can figure is that UglifyJS is generating most of them. I am using the latest versions of Node, NPM, webpack and the UglifyJS webpack plugin. I am running this on Windows. I get the same output whether I use Git Bash or PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I should clarify that the above listing of my webpack config is only part of it. It's a separate config file from the main one, and it only gets loaded if compiling in production mode (which I was). The main config has a `stats` object:

```
let webpackConfig = {
    ...
    stats         : {
        hash         : true,
        version      : true,
        timings      : true,
        children     : false,
        errors       : true,
        errorDetails : true,
        warnings     : true,
        chunks       : false,
        modules      : false,
        reasons      : true,
        source       : true,
        publicPath   : true,
    },
    ...
```

Originally, `warnings` was set to `false`, I just changed it to `true` and that fixed it. I should have posted both configs in my question so apologies.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue but setting stats to 'verbose' or { warnings: true } didn't work.