# webpack warning without message

Tags: webpack, quasar-framework

First off the answer for [webpack compiles with warnings, but the warning messages are blank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58775478/6656422) didn't not work.

I get the following on incremental builds with my quasar 1v project when using pwa mode.

> WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings
>
> warning

I tried adding both `'verbose'` and `{ warnings: true }` to the webpack config like so

```json
{
  build: {
    extendWebpack(cfg) {
      cfg.stats = 'verbose';
      // or
      cfg.stats = { warnings: true };
    }
  }
}
```

with `quasar inspect -p stats` outputting expected, but no change.

How do I investigate this warning?

ps the warning also seems to stop hot reload from working (i have to manually refresh every change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin hook was the answer.

In my case the warning was:

> InjectManifest has been called `multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.

as a string no an object so it wasn't displaying correctly. I found it by doing

my-plugin.js

```js
class MyPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap(
      "MyPlugin",
      ({ compilation } => {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(`warnings ${compilation.warnings.length}`);
        compilation.warnings.forEach((warning, index) => {
          console.log(`warning ${typeof warning}`);
          console.log(warning);
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

quasar.conf.js

```js
{
  build: {
    extendWebpack(cfg) {
      cfg.plugins = cfg.plugins || [];
      cfg.plugins.push(new MyPlugin());
    }
  }
}
```

resulting in

> WARNING Compiled with 1 warnings
>
> warning
>
> done
> warnings 1
> warning string
> InjectManifest has been called `multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.